# Email verification error because there is no get Login method

Tags: laravel, next.js, laravel-breeze

Currently I'm using Laravel Breeze integrated with Next.js but when I use the email verification function it's fine until I click on the verify link in the email it responds with this error:

> The GET method is not supported for route login. Supported methods:
> POST.

But when I log in successfully, it still hasn't verified my email
I tried adding a get method with the following path:

```php
public function getLoginInfo()
{
    $message = urlencode('Please log in to verify your email.');
    $redirectUrl = "http://localhost:3000/login?message=$message";
    Log::debug('Verification URL: not verified');
    echo "<script>
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Please login and click once again on the email address link you provided during registration to verify your email.');
            window.location.href = '$redirectUrl';
        }, 3000); // 5 seconds delay
    </script>";
   
    exit();
}
```

This is my verification controller email:

```php
public function __invoke(EmailVerificationRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect()->intended(
            config('app.frontend_url').RouteServiceProvider::HOME.'?verified=1'
        );
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
        event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return redirect()->intended(
        config('app.frontend_url').RouteServiceProvider::HOME.'?verified=1'
    );
}
```

Comment: Probable cause could be that, your login route is `Route::post()` it should be `Route::get()` please share your routes file to help investigate the issue further.